# Store aasm state value as capitalized strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aasm

I was looking to implement this wonderful gem called aasm to my existing project.
In my current project, the status column on which I am trying to add aasm, the values are saved as a capitalized string like 'Draft', 'Published' etc

How do I define my state in aasm so, that when an event to change the state is called, the value is saved correctly in capitalized form?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: why is it capitalized?  You could write a migration to lower it all and then if you need it capitalized in a view do it there.  I don't see a way to change the naming in aasm

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible. We have many external services which depend upon these values. This would lead to too many changes for us to keep those services happy.

Comment: Do those services access the database directly or via your Rails API?

Comment: have you checked if it works with capitals?

Comment: Anthony's suggestion looks best to me.

Comment: I would have loved to lower it all, but we have a couple of services which use the DB directly. Changing in all the services would be very time-consuming. I would probably have to find a workaround or if I have time then maybe downcase all.

Comment: Thanks everyone!